# Update Sequelize Array

Tags: arrays, sequelize.js

I have looked everywhere, and I have not found an easy to understand method of updating a sequelize array, like this with a normal string:

```
db.User.update({name:req.body.name},{where : {username:req.body.username}}).then(function(user) {

    res.json(user);
})
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a sequelize array - A column of the array type, an array of instances?

Comment: A column of the array type

Answer (score 5):

Sequelize doesn't support bulk updates using an array, see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4501

You have to implement a custom function.
Here is a basic example to give you an idea :

```
var promises = [];
userArray.forEach(function(user){
   promises.push(db.User.update({name:user.name},{where : {username:user.username}});
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
    // success
}, function(err){
    // error
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Which I myself resolved as follows:

case 1: If you want to update multiple lines at the same value with different conditions

```
db.User.update({ name: 'name request' }, {
    where: {
        $or: [{ name: 'test 1', password: 'sasaccsa' }, {
            name: "test 2"
        }]
    }
}).then(function(user) {
    //query generate
    // UPDATE `User` SET `name`='name request' WHERE ((`name` = 'test 1' AND `password` = 'sasaccsa') OR `name` = 'test 2')
    res.json(user);
});
```

case 2: if you want to update multiple lines with different values for different types of reviews:

```
var arrayUpdate = [{
        name: 'test 1',
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'test 2',
        id: 2
    }, {
        name: 'test 3',
        id: 3
    }];
    sequelize.Promise.each(arrayUpdate, function(val, index) {
        return db.User.update({
            name: val.name
        },{
            where:{
                id: val.id
            }
        }).then(function(user) {
        }, function(err){

        });
    })
    .then(function(updateAll){
        //done update all
         res.json(updateAll);
    }, function(err){

    });
```